# Revolut checkout widget error "Transaction failed. Please contact the merchant to resolve this problem"

Tags: integration

I have this code written with react (based on https://github.com/revolut-engineering/revolut-merchant-api-example-next-js/blob/master/db/index.js):

```
const rcRef = useRef(null);
const cardElementRef = useRef(null)

RevolutCheckout(order.token, 'sandbox').then(function (instance) {
  rcRef.current = instance.createCardField({
    target: cardElementRef.current,
    onSuccess() {
      finishOrder();
    },
    onError(message) {
      alert(`error: ${message}`)
    },
    locale: "en",
  })
});

function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const data = new FormData(event.target);

  rcRef.current.submit({
    name: data.get("name"),
    email: 'foo@bar.dev',
    phone: '0123456789',
    billingAddress: {
      countryCode: 'LT',
      region: 'Lithuania',
      city: 'Vilnius',
      streetLine1: 'Vokieciu st. 11',
      streetLine2: '',
      postcode: '12345'
    },
    savePaymentMethodFor: 'merchant',
  });
}

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <fieldset>
        <label>
          <div>Name</div>
          <input name="name"/>
        </label>
        <label>
          <div ref={cardElementRef}></div>
        </label>
      </fieldset>

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

If I remove the `savePaymentMethodFor` from submit everything works perfectly.
But with this option present (value either `merchant` or `customer`) I'm getting error `RevolutCheckout: Transaction failed. Please contact the merchant to resolve this problem`.

Has anyone seen this? Revolut docs aren't very useful here.

Tried different options, expecting successful checkout request and saved customer.

UPDATE:
The problem was with order creation.
Server-side code before:

```
exports.createOrderForProduct = async (product) => {
  const payload = {
    description: `Payment for ${product.name}`,
    amount: product.price.amount,
    currency: product.price.currency,
  };

  const apiResponse = await revolutClient.post(`https://sandbox-merchant.revolut.com/api/1.0/orders`,payload);
  const payment = apiResponse.data;
  console.log('Revolut order create', payment)

  return {
    id: payment.id,
    token: payment.public_id,
  }
};
```

After:

```
exports.createOrderForProduct = async (product) => {
  const payload = {
    description: `Payment for ${product.name}`,
    amount: product.price.amount,
    currency: product.price.currency,
    customer: {
      email: '...'
    }
  };

  const apiResponse = await revolutClient.post(`https://sandbox-merchant.revolut.com/api/orders`,payload, {
    headers: {
      'Revolut-Api-Version': '2023-09-01'
    }
  });
  const payment = apiResponse.data;
  console.log('Revolut order create', payment)

  return {
    id: payment.id,
    token: payment.token,
  }
};
```

The example was using deprecated version of the API and my payload was missing customer details.
https://developer.revolut.com/docs/merchant/create-order